# Wheel get stuck intermediate slightly during continuous rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

Currently working on functionality where wheel starts rotating slowly when user touch on the wheel, then gradually increase speed to max level then again slow down gradually. this animation achieved using `CGAffineTransformRotate`. Here we will provide the continuous angle to rotate the wheel. During this process, if any notification received or any main thread activity like web service call, etc. then wheel get slightly pause(Get slightly jark).

Example:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
            _imgWheel.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(_imgWheel.transform, degreesToRadians(-angle));
        }];
```

Can anyone guide me how to come out from this difficulty?

Thanks

Comment: *"any main thread activity like web service call"* - why are you making network calls on the main thread? That's never a good idea.

Comment: @rmaddy, No actual web service call are alway made in backgroud thread but when execution completed, we need to bring it in main thread.